# Queue with lock vs Lock Free Queue

Tags: multithreading, c++11, boost, producer-consumer, lock-free

I am involved a task of listening to a web service. Which will send a xml data through push service. The data have to undergo some calculation and then it will we displayed.

I have planned to use queue to store the data by service listener and read the data by the business logic code. It is a pure single producer single consumer queue.

Since I have to receive the data as web service push, I have to always open to receive the data and push it to the queue. I thought of using `boost_lockfree_spsc_queue`. Because, if it were a lockable queue the listener have to wait for a while to acquire the lock, as opposed to it `boost_lockfree_spsc_queue` does not need any locks.

The data I am going to store is

```
struct MemoryStruct {
    char *memory;
    size_t size;
};
```

And the queue is

```
boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<MemoryStruct*> lockFreeQ{100};
```

After reading performance section here I got bit confused.

Is it safe to use this boost_lockfree_spcc_queue for production purposes. Or should I use standard queue (C++ 11 )with locks?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is safe for production uses - as long as you abide to the usage requirements. What section made you confused?

Comment: You use that `MemoryStruct` but are worried that `boost` will screw up your program?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using MemoryStruct ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe(http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/lockfree.html#lockfree.introduction___motivation.introduction__amp__terminology ) When discussing the performance of non-blocking data structures, one has to distinguish between amortized and worst-case costs. The definition of 'lock-free' and 'wait-free' only mention the upper bound of an operation. Therefore lock-free data structures are not necessarily the best choice for every use case. In order to maximise the throughput of an application one should consider high-performance concurrent data structures

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you expect the load to not saturate your CPU you will just bump the electricity bill. The usual approach is exponential back-off. ¹

If you're not at all sure about this, then this smells a lot like premature optimization, and you can probably use a locking queue.

You could make sure your usage patterns make it easy to swap in a lock free implementation. Make your own blocking `pop()` function that would wrap the wait logic in case of a lock-free implementation.

¹ see e.g. http://kukuruku.co/hub/cpp/lock-free-data-structures-the-evolution-of-a-stack

Comment: I am sorry I am still bit unclear about your statement “Make your own blocking pop() function that would wrap the wait logic in case of a lock-free implementation.”

Comment: Making my own booking pop() means surround pop() using lock() and unlock().  What is meant by wrapping wait logic incase of lock-free? lock free mean wait free right ? Then why should I warp lock-free implementation using wait logic ?

Comment: TL;DR use a locking queue. Optionally, play around with lock-free queues so you see the difference(s) in interface (e.g. there'd be no `size()` or `empty()` calls). That will make it easier for you to migrate to the lock-less queue in a future version should you find out you need one after all. Just, one step at a time. Look at the things you do understand, expand your knowledge _one step at a time_ - follow your curiosity. Making jumps just leads to holes in your experience/understanding.

Comment: Re. "Making my own booking pop() means surround pop() using lock() and unlock()" - certainly not. That would be using an unlocked queue, by synchronizing access externally. That's not what a blocking queue does. It locks internally. **Forget about my wrapping suggestion, see previous comment.**

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply and introducing me to these jargons.  I will read more about it and come back.

Comment: Hi, I have done some googling on booking pop() and I tried to implement it  `void sharedQueue::lockFreeConsume() {   for(i till 100) { while(!(lockFreeQ.read_available() > 0))
                { 
                   std::this_thread::yield() ;
               }
       
           lockFreeQ.pop(); } } `  Is this right? (Sorry for the poor formatting)